# Android sensor to detect temperature

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to detect temperature with my phone(not saying about battery temp)?
I would like my phone to be able to detect a low temp in the fridge.

Comment: You can refer this link [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment.html#kotlin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment.html#kotlin) you can also check complete example from :
[https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_Ambient_Temperature](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_Ambient_Temperature)

Answer (score 0):

For your phone to be able to detect its environments temperature, (e.g Detecting the temperature when your phone is in your fridge), the Android phone uses its `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE` sensor to do this. The `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE` sensor senses the environments temperature and returns the temp in ºC (degree celcius) which can be converted to other temperature measurement using simple Programming logic.

You can Access the API documentation on how to use the temperature sensor in your android app [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#java)